# Blue Prism identify using UI Automation: 2 edit fields with the same name

Tags: ui-automation, blueprism

I'm working with a windows application and at a certain point I should select an edit field to be filled with some text. The problem is that next to the field it's a button and next to the button it's another field that (in the UI Automation helper) has the same name as the first one. Blue Prism is throwing an error: More than one element matched the query terms. How can I select just the first field? If I can't do that, is any option to change the name of the second field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to check the "Match" checkbox for the "Match Index" property for each of the two entries in the Application Modeler and test to see which responds to a value of `1`, and which responds to a value of `2`.

It's important to note that this will more often than not make your solution more sensitive to interface changes within the target application.